# How to add / change group prices with Magento API 1.9.1

Tags: api, ce-1.9.1.0

I can't find a way to add or change the group prices with the API.
Its only possible to change the tier prices.
Have anyone a idea, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no existing APIs available for changing group prices, but you can create a custom API.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060295/how-to-update-group-price-via-soap-api

Comment: I tried it and created the module. But its not working.
I can't read / update the product. I used:`code`var_dump($client_m->call($session_m, 'product_group_price.info', 51199));
The Code won't work with "product_group", i testet "product_tier" and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060295/how-to-update-group-price-via-soap-api

in config.xml the  `</config>` is missing ang in wsdl.xml the `</definitions>` is missing put the two ad the end of each file. it worked for me.